# 100 fowls problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

If a cock is worth 5 qians, a hen 3 qians, and three chicks together 1 qian, how many
cocks, hens, and chicks, totaling 100, can be bought for 100 coins?

So if , $x$ is the number of cocks,
$y$ is the number of hens, $z$ the number of chicks such that

$5x + 3y + z/3
 = 100$

$x + y + z = 100$

Then i further solve it and find only three possible solutions of it which satisfying all requirement
[image]

[image]

But then why my book is saying this problem as a " indeterminate problem " or am i doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Your final paragraph ("But according to me...") exactly describes the two given equations.

Comment: @DanielMathias please see the edit

Comment: "Indeterminate" doesn't mean no solution. It means equations have non-unique solutions. Here I obtain four solutions : $(0,25,75),(4,18,78),(8,11,81),(12,4,84)$.

Comment: Also, $x+y=2$ has infinitely-many and hence indeterminate solutions.

Comment: @MyMolecules so we have so many indeterminate equation . Is there anything special to this problem so that my book give so much importance to it ??

Comment: Yes. We can parameterize the multiple solutions and later on, one learns to write these. For example the ordered pair $(t,2-t)$ represents those infinitely many solutions to $x+y=2$. In the four solutions to your question, do you notice any pattern?

Comment: Corresponding numbers are in arithmetic progression!